# service stop doesn't run the exit/cleanup part

Tags: services, daemon, upstart

This is a sleeping service,

```
import time
bufsize = 0
f = open("/home/user/sleep-log", "w", bufsize)
try:
  f.write("going for a deep sleep......")
  time.sleep( 1000000000)
except:
  import traceback; f.write(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
  f.write("that is surprising.. final block just ran")
```

And i have a ubuntu upstart task to run this,

```
description "sleeper"
author "saravana"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
script
  exec /usr/bin/python /home/user/a.py
end script
```

When i do,

```
service  sleeper start
service sleeper stop
```

the log file contains,

```
going for a deep sleep.......
```

`Finally` block is skipped. How can i ensure my cleanup code will always run? I can do it in conf file using `post stop script` but for legacy reasons, i want to do it inside python file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Upstart stops a job it sends the `SIGTERM` signal. By default `SIGTERM` causes the program to immediately exit. This means the execution does not flow through the rest of your code, it simply stops.

A signal handler can be implemented using the `signal` module, you can find details on it's usage [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html). This will allow you to run code upon receiving the signal.